# steering wheel angle control

Tags: control-engineering, pid-control, matlab, stepper-motor, simulink

I am working on an autonomous vehicle's control, specifically the steering wheel angle control.
Knowing that I used kinematic bicycle model, my questions are:

- How do I choose the actuator for my steering wheel angle?
- why did the article (below) use a stepper motor?
- according to what do we choose an actuator to build a control system for steering angle control?
  I appreciate your help.

[image: article]

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/664519/152903

Comment: You choose a motor by figuring your constraints. Stepper motors get a lot of capability (in this case, torque, speed, resolution) per cost, but are inefficient by energy spent. Alternative is a feedback-based system (sensors are costly).

Comment: thank you @Abel